# Toggle between list group and div on item click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a HTML page, where the top half is static and the bottom half is dynamic. In the mobile view of this page, the bottom half is a list group with each item representing a category.

On clicking any item, I want the list group to vanish and the details for that category should be visible on the screen. Also, the static part above should not be affected. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any code to show ?

Comment: Post the code you have done so far.

Comment: No, not really. I just have the basic list group code:
<div class="list-group card only-mobile">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-nav-item">Category 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-nav-item">Category 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-nav-item">Category 3</a>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve using ui-router and the multi named views or nested views :

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

```
 $stateProvider.state('nestedViews', {
        url: '/nested-views',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'components/nestedViews/partial-nested-views.html'
            },
            'columnOne@nestedViews': {
                templateUrl: 'components/nestedViews/partial-nested-views-content.html'
            },
            'columnTwo@nestedViews': {
                templateUrl: 'components/nestedViews/partial-nested-views-menu.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

In Your HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div ui-view="columnOne"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div ui-view="columnTwo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your inputs

```
<a ui-sref="the_state" class="list-group-item list-group-nav-item">Category 1</a>
```